# Encoding number to date time

Tags: c, encoding

I have 32 bit encoded value for date and time value.I know the sample 32bit encoded value date and time but i don't know how to convert and get this value using c program or any other language or script. The sample data as below

```
54 FE C0 72 =(25-Oct-13 20:34:58)
55 01 DC 8B =(26-Oct-13 22:34:51)
57 01 DC 8B =(14-Apr-14 14:34:51)
42 23 8F 96 =(02-Jun-09 17:06:30)
3C F5 28 4B= (31-Mar-00 18:51:55)
3A F4 28 49 =(12-Oct-99 18:51:53)
```

For the above sample data i am tried using unix timestamp method but i am getting wrong date time value.The answers using unix time stamp method as below

```
54 FE C0 72 =(10 Mar 2015 09:59:14 GMT
55 01 DC 8B =(12 Mar 2015 18:35:55 GMT)
57 01 DC 8B =(04 Apr 2016 03:16:27 GMT)
```

Please give me your guidance to convert the above 32bit encoded value to correct date and time value. And please share any other methods other than unix timestamp.And i think some algorithms are encrypted inside the hex code

EDIT:

Adding examples from [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88190/discussion-between-lps-and-rmrps):

```
30067004 =24-mar-1997 07:57:56
2C067004=Tue Apr 16 23:57:56 1996
29567004=Thu Aug 31 15:57:56 1995
13567004=9-jul-90 7:57:56
17567004=15-jun-91 15:57:56
1C567004=15-aug-92 07:57:56
20567004=23-jul-93 15:57:56
24867004=15-jul-94 23:57:56
10067004=29 sep-89 15:57:56
2B067004=21-jan-96 15:57:56

00000000 = 1-Jan-1986
00030000 = 1-jan-1986
00038000 = 1-jan-1994
```

Comment: Is there a time zone associated with the converted values? Even if that is UTC? Are the values always convertible without additional data? So, if you were to generate the same hexadecimal values, say, tomorrow, would they point to the same date/time values?

Comment: Also, in your question, you're saying you "don't know how to convert and get this value using c program", but the question is tagged with JavaScript.

Comment: Unix is right. 54 FE C0 72 will is 14259815554 seconds from 1/1/1970, or 396105 hours, or 16504 days, or 45 years. What system are you using?

Comment: do you know where the sample data comes from? dbush' answer is good, but it niggles me that it's a day out on the last sample. If you're reverse-engineering a format someone invented for a single purpose with a single implementation, there may be bugs in the format or the implementation. Could the system that generated the hex timestamps drift from true time and the system that converts the hex to dates try correcting it?

Comment: Those last two samples ('00 and '99) break the pattern of the others

Comment: is there a typo in `30067004 =24-mar-1997 07:56:56` - should it be `07:57:56`?

Comment: another typo: from the chat, `2C067004 =15 apr-96 23:57:56` and `29567004=30 aug-95 15:57:56` - in the edit, they've become 16 april and 31 august respectively

Comment: @Dse, could you add the following dates please? `00008000` (to check with 00038000 similar to 00000000/00030000); `0945F004`, `0948F004` and `094BF004` which I think should be on 28 Feb through 1 Mar 1996, and `04FBF004`, `04FEF004` and `0501F004`, which I think should be 28 Feb through 2 Mar 1995. I don't think there's any test cases for the 1994 epoch on leap years, or before the leap day.

Comment: Please don't remove the contents of your question.  Doing so puts the answers out of context.  SO is meant as a long term repository of programming knowledge, so answered questions shouldn't be robbed of their content like that.

Comment: Has any of the answers fully answered your question? If so, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) one of them. If there are still problems, please edit your question to clarify your problem a bit more and post a comment about that under (some) answers.

Answer (score 10):

Let's start by looking at the first two:

```
54 FE C0 72 =(25-oct-13 20:34:58)
54 FE C0 78 =(25-oct-13 20:35:04)
```

These two dates are 6 seconds apart, and the values differ by 6.  So we know that at least the last byte specifies seconds.

```
55 01 DC 8B =(26-oct-13 22:34:51)
55 01 E3 93 =(26-oct-13 23:04:51)
```

Similarly, these two are are 30 minutes (1800 seconds) apart, and the values differ by 1800.  So at least the last two bytes specify seconds.

```
54 FE C0 78 =(25-oct-13 20:35:04)
55 01 DC 8B =(26-oct-13 22:34:51)
```

There's a larger range in the values, but note that the last two bytes seem to be fairly close in value.  Taking DC8Bh - C078h gives us 1C13h = 7187d.  That's a difference of 2 hours (7200 seconds) minus 13 seconds, which is how far apart the time portions of the two dates are.  So it looks like the last two bytes specify the time.  However, there are 86400 seconds in a day, and C078h = 49272d which would be closer to around 13:00:00 than 20:35:04, that and the largest value you can store in 16 bits is 65535.  Also, the first two bytes differ by 3 but the dates differ by 1.  Let's come back to that in a bit.

```
55 01 DC 8B =(26-oct-13 22:34:51)
57 01 DC 8B =(14-Apr-14 14:34:51)
```

Note here that the last two bytes are the same, and that the minutes and seconds are the same, although the hours differ by 8.  So perhaps the last two bytes specify seconds in part of a day.  Going back to the prior example, the first two bytes differed by 3 when the dates differed by 1.  So perhaps the first two bytes specify an 8 hour interval.  This would account for the last two bytes being the same when the time differs by 8 or 16 hours.  If we take 5701h - 5501h we get 200h = 512d.  Dividing by 3 we get 169 2/3 days.  The two dates above differ by 170 days, and if you take the hours into account it's about 169 2/3.

So now we have dates.  5501h is the third 8-hour interval in 26-oct-13, so the start of the day is 54FFh = 21759d.  Dividing by 3 gives us 7253.  Counting back days, that gives us an epoch date of 1993-12-17.

Now lets go back to the time.  Assuming the last two bytes are seconds in an 8-hour interval.  That gives us a maximum value of 28800d.  Note that this value only needs 15 bits to store.  DC8Bh has the highest bit set, so let's see what we get if we mask that bit out.  That gives us 5C8Bh = 23691d, and 23691 seconds is 6 hours 34 minutes 51 seconds.  That matches the third and fifth examples with a difference of 8 hours.

As for the most significant bit in the third byte, my guess is that is specifies DST.  All the examples have this bit set, and all the dates are when DST is active.

So to summarize:

- The first two bytes divided by 3 is number of days since 1993-12-17.
- The first two bytes mod 3 is the 8-hour interval in the day.  Multiply this value by 28800 (i.e. seconds in 8 hours) to set the initial time in seconds.
- The last two bytes with the most significant bit masked out are seconds from the start of the 8-hour interval.  Add this value to the value from the prior step to get seconds from midnight.
- Check the most significant bit in the third byte to set the DST flag.

EDIT:

So it seems the result this algorithm gives for `57 01 DC 8B =(14-Apr-14 14:34:51)` is ahead by one day.  Let's look at one of the new examples:

```
42 23 8F 96 =(02-Jun-09 17:06:30)
```

Our algorithm give a date of 30-May-09, so it's behind by 3 days.  This is interesting because it differs from what we got for 25-Oct-13 and 26-Oct-13 by about 4 years.  What's different is that there's a leap year in between.  So perhaps this encoding is assuming all years have 366 days.  If we go back to the epoch date of 1993-12-17, we see that there are 15 non-leap years from 1994 to 2013 inclusive.  That give us a new epoch date of 1994-1-1, which makes more sense.  So after doing the initial conversion with 1994-1-1 as the epoch, we need to count the number of non-leap years and subtract that many days.

Now let's look at this one:

```
3A F4 28 49 =(12-Oct-99 18:51:53)
```

The time is still correct, but the date is way off.  Notice however that the most significant bit of byte 3 is NOT set.  This seems to indicate a different epoch.  The start of 12-Oct-99 is 3AF2h = 15090d.  Dividing by 3 gives us 5030.  Counting backward gives us an epoch of 1986-01-03.  But then there's this:

```
00000000 = 1-Jan-1986
00030000 = 1-jan-1986
```

So it looks like 1986-1-1 is the epoch, but there's a special case in place for this date, so the actual epoch is 1985-12-31.

*But*, we're off by 3 days.  If all years had 366 days, this would not be the case.  It would work however if all years had 365 days.  This means that for the 1985-12-31 epoch, we need to count the number of leap years and add that many days.  This is the opposite of what we need to do with the 1994-1-1 epoch.

This now works for *almost* everything.  Everything except these:

```
3C F5 28 4B= (31-Mar-00 18:51:55)
1C567004=15-aug-92 07:57:56
```

But it does work for this:

```
2B067004=21-jan-96 15:57:56
```

So it looks like this encoding does do a leap year check, *but only for the current year*.

Taking these changes to the algorithm and applying them to the code provided by LPs, we now have this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

int isleap(int year)
{
    if (year % 4 != 0) return 0;
    if (year % 100 != 0) return 1;
    if (year % 400 != 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Read encoding from command line
    uint32_t datetime = strtoul(argv[1],NULL,16);

    uint16_t mydate = datetime >> 16;
    uint16_t mytime = datetime & 0xFFFF;

    int new_encoding = (mytime & 0x8000) != 0;

    // Calculate days
    time_t linuxSeconds = (mydate/3);
    // Calculate the 8 hours on current day of date
    uint8_t third_Count = mydate % 3;

    // Add days from 1/1/1970, that is the base of time in linux
    if (new_encoding)
    {
        // Days between 1970-1-1 and 1994-1-1 minus 1
        linuxSeconds += 8765;
    }
    else
    {
        // Days between 1970-1-1 and 1986-1-1 minus 1
        linuxSeconds += 5843;
    }

    // Calculate total amount of hours
    linuxSeconds *= 24;

    // Calculate total amount of seconds
    linuxSeconds *= 3600;

    // Add seconds of last 8 hours group
    linuxSeconds += (mytime & 0x7FFF);

    // Add alla seconds of grups of 8 hours of date
    linuxSeconds += (third_Count * 28800);

    // Add or subtract days depending on whether new_encoding is set
    struct tm *mytm = gmtime(&linuxSeconds);
    int daydiff = 0, year;
    for (year = new_encoding ? 1994 : 1986; year <= mytm->tm_year + 1900; year++) {
        if (year < mytm->tm_year + 1900) {
            if (new_encoding) {
                // remove a day for non-leap years
                if (!isleap(year)) {
                    daydiff--;
                }
            } else {
                // add a day for leap years unless it's the current year
                if (year != (mytm->tm_year + 1900) && isleap(year)) {
                    daydiff++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (mydate < 0x0003) {
        // special case for day 0
        linuxSeconds += 86400;
    } else {
        linuxSeconds += daydiff * 86400;
    }

    // Print the date with actual GMT
    printf(ctime(&linuxSeconds));

    // Print Greenwich time
    printf(asctime(gmtime(&linuxSeconds)));

    return 0;
}
```

One caveat about this code: if it's run on a system where `time_t` is 32-bit, it won't be able to properly display dates after 2038.  If `time_t` is 64-bit, those dates will display properly.

EDIT 2:

There was an issue with code 30068000 being one day ahead.  There was a bug in the code when checking the current month.  The `tm_mon` field in `struct tm` ranges from 0 to 11, not 1 to 12.  Fixed.

EDIT 3:

So it seems the month/day check when adding/subtracting days was just plain wrong, as it was causing Feb 28 to appear twice.  When I removed that, I found that the 1994 scheme was a day ahead, so it looks like it has the same special case for day 0 that the 1986 scheme has.  Fixed again.

Comment: 512 / 3 = 170 2/3, not 169 2/3. It would work if 2014 was treated as a leap year.

Comment: @rmrps This date encoding uses 1993-12-17 as day 0.  If you want to convert to unix time, you need to add 8751 days to that.  See the answer provided by LPs for an example on how that's done.

Comment: @dbush: Thanks for your effort.

Comment: The difference of 8751 days between 1970-01-01 and 1993-12-17 accounts for all leap days.  Once you have the unix time, you can use `ctime()`, `localtime()`, or `gmtime()` to get the date properly with all of the built-in checks for leap years.

Comment: @dbush,@LPs  i have added one more sample data 42 23 8F 96 =(02-Jun-09 17:06:30) but it will differ 3 days

Comment: 30068000=13-mar-05 00:00:00 but as per your coding its giving 14-mar-05 00:00:00 1day differ

Comment: As per your program gives C0068000=Mon Oct  6 17:31:44 1902  but C0068000=9-oct-38 00:00:00

Comment: @rmrps In order for dates after 2038 to display properly, you need to run the code on a system where `time_t` is 64-bit.

Comment: there's still the inconsistency on 30068000. I'd also like to see some more test values: `00008000`, plus some dates before/on 29 Feb/1Mar on leap years and non-leap years, especially with the first 1994 epoch

Answer (score 3):

Using the perfect explanation of @dbush, below you can find a simple linux gcc compiled code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>


void decrypt ( uint32_t data )
{
    uint16_t mydate = data>>16;
    uint16_t mytime = data&0x0000FFFF;

    // Calculate days
    time_t linuxSeconds = (mydate/3);
    // Calculate the 8 hours on current day of date
    uint8_t third_Count = mydate % 3;

    // Add days from 1/1/1970, that is the base of time in linux
    if (mytime&0x8000)
    {
       // Days from 171/1970 to 17/12/1993
       linuxSeconds += 8751;
    }
    else
    {
       // Days from 171/1970 to 19/03/1984
       linuxSeconds += 5846;
    }

    // Calculate total amount of hours
    linuxSeconds *= 24;

    // Calculate total amount of seconds
    linuxSeconds *= 3600;

    // Add seconds of last 8 hours group
    linuxSeconds += (mytime&0x7FFF);

    // Add alla seconds of grups of 8 hours of date
    linuxSeconds += (third_Count * 28800);

    // Print the date with actual GMT
//  printf(ctime(&linuxSeconds));

    // Print Greenwich time
    printf(asctime(gmtime(&linuxSeconds)));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    decrypt(0x54FEC072);
    decrypt(0x5501DC8B);
    decrypt(0x5701DC8B);
    decrypt(0x42238F96);
    decrypt(0x3CF5284B);
    decrypt(0x3AF42849);

    return 0;
}
```

As @rmrps pointed out the last example is out of 1 day.

**OUTPUT OF THE EXAMPLE ABOVE**

> - Fri Oct 25 20:34:58 2013
> - Sat Oct 26 22:34:51 2013
> - Tue Apr 15 14:34:51 2014
> - Sat May 30 17:06:30 2009
> - Fri Mar 31 18:51:55 2000
> - Tue Oct 12 18:51:53 1999

Comment: @rmrps I added days from 1/1/1970 to 17/12/1993 because of linux base time used by time.h. Output is exact what you wrote in your post, but localized. In my case GMT+1 (Italy)

Comment: @rmrps I'm not getting you. The output is the one shown in your post. Is 1 hours more because of the GMT difference. Do you means: how to take care of GMT?

Comment: @rmrps I edited. The example now show you how to retrieve and correct the timezone of the machine where the program is executed.

Comment: @rmrps Once you have the unix time, calling `ctime(&linuxSeconds)` will give you a textual representation of the time for you local timezone.  This call is equivalent to `asctime(localtime(&linuxSeconds))`.  This fully accounts for leaps years and DST for your time zone.  If you want to print the time in GMT, call `asctime(gmtime(&linuxSeconds))` instead.

Comment: @rmrps Yes, all of those functions are available in C by including time.h.

Comment: @rmrps could you post two dates near 2K? I means, eg: 31/12/1999 and 15/03/2000. The date after 2K  must be after february.

Comment: @rmrps It is very strange that `42 23` and `3C F5` has a difference of `1326` units and dates differs of `3360` days...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88190/discussion-between-lps-and-rmrps).

Answer (score 3):

Building on dbush' excellent analysis, there still one issue regarding the days.
This can be explained by the format, instead of counting days since epoch counts years since epoch and day of year, but ignoring leap years and using a fixed 366 day year. This sets the epoch to 31 December 1993.

So from the `days_since_epoch` part in dbush' answer, calculate `years_since_epoch = days_since_epoch / 366` and `day_of_year = days_since_epoch % 366`. Set the epoch at 1993-12-31, and add the lapsed time since epoch (taking leap days into account), and you'll get the correct dates from the timestamp.

The last two timestamps you added doesn't fit dbush' analysis and so seem follow a different format. Note that the bit that dbush assumed was a DST indicator is no longer set - it actually appears to be a date scheme selector rather than DST indicator.
The date part of the last two examples is simpler - it's simply days since epoch (but a different epoch - 3 January 1986).

**Edit: following discussion in chat, I'm updating my code samples.**

Because my implementation - and some of the results differ from dbush' implementation and results, I'm adding an explanation as well.

If the format is based on 4 hex bytes AA BB CC DD, we treat this as a big-endian 32-bit number (AA msb = bit 31, DD lsb = bit 0), the hex timestamp is decoded as follows:

- bits 0-14:        number of seconds into a 8-hour window
- bit 15:           date scheme/epoch selector (see below)
- bits 31-16 mod 3: the 8-hour window of the day.
- bits 31-16 div 3: an indication of days since epoch (let's call it `day_count`)

`day_count` is not the actual number of days as both schemes treats every year as having a fixed number of days. It also includes the current (partial) day, so we should remove the partial day by subtracting one from `day_count`. This also means that a zero `day_count` is probably invalid (This has been confirmed for one of the two schemes `00000000` and `00030000` yield the same date - if `00008000` and `00038000` yield the same value it also holds for the other scheme)

For each scheme, there are only two parameters that differ between the schemes, `epoch` and `days_per_year`. Given these parameters, the calculation is the same - work out the following:

- `years_since_epoch   = day_count / days_per_year`
- `days_since_new_year = day_count % days_per_year // whole days`

Then calculate the actual number of days since epoch as `days_since_new_year` plus the number of days in each year since epoch, taking leap days into account.

The two schemes are selected by bit 15:

- If 1, `epoch` is 1994-01-01 and `days_per_year` is 366
- If 0, `epoch` is 1986-01-01 and `days_per_year` is 365

The following code decodes both timestamp formats:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

int isLeapYear( int y )
{
    if ( y % 400 == 0 )   return 1;
    if ( y % 100 == 0 )   return 0;
    if ( y % 4 == 0 )   return 1;
    return 0;
}

time_t decodeTimestamp (uint32_t timestamp)
{
    time_t result = 0;
    int y, days_since_new_year, years_since_epoch, epoch_year;

    int day_count      = (timestamp >> 16 ) /3;
    int part_of_day    = (timestamp >> 16 ) %3;
    int seconds_in_day = part_of_day * 8 * 3600 + ( (timestamp & 0x7FFF) % 28800 ) ;

    if ( day_count > 0 )
    {
        --day_count;  // remove current (partial) day from day_count
    }
    if ( ((timestamp >> 15) & 1) == 1 ) // bit 15 is date scheme
    {
        days_since_new_year = day_count % 366;
        years_since_epoch   = day_count / 366;
        epoch_year          = 1994;

        result = 757382400; //1994-01-01
    }
    else
    {
        days_since_new_year = day_count % 365;
        years_since_epoch   = day_count / 365;
        epoch_year          = 1986;

        result = 504921600;//1986-01-01
    }
    result += years_since_epoch * 365 *24*60*60;
    for ( y = epoch_year ; y < epoch_year + years_since_epoch; ++y )
    {
        if ( isLeapYear( y ) )
        {
            result += 24 * 60 * 60;
        }
    }
    result += days_since_new_year * 24 * 60 * 60;
    result += seconds_in_day;
    return result;
}
```

I've put this up on http://codepad.org/K4JC0zmf, which also includes a main function which test against all of the examples I've seen in this thread. The only one it falls over is `C0068000`, which is explained by time_t being 32 bits not 64 bits.

**Edit 2: Updated dbush' implementation in the side-by-side on codepad.**

I've also put both mine and dbush' (current) implementation on http://codepad.org/vMYzNM4g to see the differences.

Both methods give the same correct results, apart from the 2038 overflow case (`C0068000`). I expect that they would give the same result with a 64-bit time_t however, so I think both algorithms are now correct.

Comment: The case for dates with a 1986 epoch is not correct.  See the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88190/discussion-between-lps-and-rmrps) we've got going on.

Comment: Nice analysis.  It helped me identify issues with my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
E393 - DC8B = 1800
23:04:51 - 22:34:51 = 1800s

(10 Mar 2015 09:59:14 GMT - 25-oct-13 20:34:58) = 43248256 seconds
```

Try subtracting 43248256 decimal (293EA80 hex) from the number and then use it as if it was a unix time stamp:

```
54FEC072h - 293EA80h = 526AD5F2h = 1382733298d = "Fri, 25 Oct 2013 20:34:58 GMT"
```